# Problem with referencing files via "FILE:EXT" in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I just upgraded a TYPO3 extension with cal and had an exception. This was resolved by changing the constant:

> plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.listTemplate =
>   FILE:EXT:somextkey/somepath/list.tmpl

to

> plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.listTemplate =
>   EXT:someextkey/somepath/list.tmpl

While the latter is how it is documented in the [cal docs](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/cal/Advanced/TyposcriptReferenceConstants/Index.html) and should have been used in the first place, this is an easy mistake to make, because often `FILE:EXT` is actually used to reference files. I don't know why this worked in TYPO3 8 and not in TYPO3 9.

The part that broke was

```
$absPath = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->getFileName($path);
```

with $path being the path as defined by the constant.

Also, on this page [TypoScript Syntax: Includes](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptSyntaxReference/7.6/Syntax/Includes/Index.html) both variants are used:

and

Is there an easy to remember rule what is to be used when, is the variant "FILE:EXT" deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FILE:EXT:` is only for inclusion because there we have also `DIR:EXT:`. For templates you always need `EXT:`. The only other exception is with languages: `LLL:EXT:`. It is like this since TYPO3 3.x.

Comment: Ah, you mean inclusion of TypoScript files? Ok, that makes sense.